# django relation between two many to many fields

Tags: python, django

I have following model structure for my application.I have following models,

1. Product
2. ProductGroup
3. Attribute

Currently i am working on another two models(`which are some how related with the above three models`) , namely

1. FacetHeader
2. FacetLines

what i have do is that, `i have to find a Attribute from a particular ProductGroup` where `Attribute` is a `ForeignKey` in `FacetLines` models and `ProductGroup` is `ForeignKey` in `FacetHeader`.

**In mention** `Attribute` and `ProductGroup` has also `ManyToMany` relationship with `Product` model.

but this is really a hard going for me,as i am a new comer in Djang0 and my model structure is bit complex for me,.So please take a look at my models structure bellow,(Here i am sequentially representing my model)

**FacetHeader**

```
class FacetHeader(AbstractBaseModel):

    """
    Defining the facets header that will be used during search.
    """

    validators = [ChainIntegrityValidator, ScreenMethodValidator]

    product_group = models.ForeignKey(
        'products.ProductGroup',
        help_text=_('The product group in which the facet header belongs'),
        verbose_name=_('product group')
        )
```

**FacetLines**

```
 class FacetLines(AbstractBaseModel):

    """
    Defining the facets lines that will be used during search.
    """

    validators = [ChainIntegrityValidator, ScreenMethodValidator]

    facet_header = models.ForeignKey(
        'search.FacetHeader',
        help_text=_('facet header to which facet lines belongs'),
        verbose_name=_('facet header')
        )
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        'products.Attribute',
        help_text=_("attribute to which facet lines belongs"),
        verbose_name=_("attribute"),
        )
```

and **Product**

```
class Product(AbstractBaseModel):
    """
    Describes product. products are basically parent  product that does not
    have a sku. For example, a product can be an Iphone 5, but the sku are the variants which
    can be something like Iphone 5 Black, Iphone 5 Grey, etc.
    """

    product_group = models.ManyToManyField(ProductGroup,
                                       blank=True)

    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute,
                                    blank=True,
                                    verbose_name=_("attributes"),
                                    help_text=_('Select Attributes of  product'),
                                    through='ProductAttribute')
```

and this is the **ProductAttribute** model

```
class ProductAttribute(AbstractAttribute):
    """
    This is the through models that holds attribute value
    for products

    """

    validators = [ScreenMethodValidator, ChainIntegrityValidator]

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                            related_name='attribute_values',
                            verbose_name=_("Product"))
    value_option = models.ManyToManyField(Option,
                                      blank=True,
                                      null=True,
                                      verbose_name=_("Option"))
```

so how can i get all the `Attributes` of a particular `ProductGroup`(i.e product_group_pk=1) using `FacetHeader` and `FacetLines` models.

**UPDATE**
Here i am creating `FacetHeader` with multiple `FacetLines` using a inline formset where `FacetHeader` is a `parent` form and `FacetLines` are child forms.

What i exactly need to do is that,

`when i select a particular product group from FacetHeader model` then in the `FacetLines forms,there should be appear attribute of that selected product group of FacetHeader model`.

Comment: Have you tried something. This should not be that complex. You just have to follow the ForeignKey relation from `FacetLines` -> `FacetHeader` -> `ProductGroup` in your QuerySet.

Comment: So you are saying ,it will solve the problem,but here `ProductGroup` do not have any `Foreign` or `Many to many` relation with `Attribute`,can you please add another  comment or add an answer with appropiate one? @RohitJain

Comment: You get all the `FacetLines` for a given `ProductGroup`. And then you get the attributes from all those `FacetLines`.

Comment: can you please give it as an answer?@RohitJain

Comment: Ok, posted an answer. Please try it out.